# Xcode bundle path

Tags: swift, xcode, nsbundle

I have this:

```
guard let dbPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "FluidDatabase",
                                         ofType: "sqlite",
                                    inDirectory: "Models") else {
    assertionFailure()
    return
}
```

And the file resides here:
MainAppFolder/Models/FluidDatabase.sqlite.

It keeps getting caught by the assertionFailure.

Comment: Doesn't it need to be in `Application.app/Contents/Resources/Models/FluidDatabase.sqlite`?

Comment: @user1118321: This depends on the operating system. On iOS it must be in the path of the OP. On macOS your path is right.

Comment: Does the file get copied properly at build time? It doesn't end in the root app folder? Might want to give it a try to the same method, but without the `directory` param, to see if it can find the file this way.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have passed unnecessary "Models" into inDirectory, If you have added that Sqlite file as a reference file into your project, Then you can directly able to get it's path from bundle.

**Swift 4**

```
    guard let dbPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "FluidDatabase",ofType: "sqlite",inDirectory: nil)
        else {
                assertionFailure()
                return
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so the problem was that the file was not included in the Target Membership of my project in the File Inspector.